# Most efficient way to store data from 2d Array onto a stack

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array, queue, stack

Suppose I have a container filled with numbers like this:

```
1 1 1 1 2 1
1 2 1 1 1 1
1 2 3 4 5 1
```

and I'm provided with a C++ self made Stack/Queue like this:

```
tepmlate<class T>
class Stack{
   void push(const T& n){
    ..
   }
  
  private:
    int* _stack;
   ...
}

template<class T>
class Queue{
..
```

I'm wondering what is the best way to store this numbers so that I can push and pop the datas at the top (1 1 1 1 2 1) efficiently without the use of the common 2d array initialization.

My first thought it to make a vector of class **Stack** to represent the column and use the array **_stack** to represent row. But I read another post on stack overflow that this is not the desired usage of class.

Another method that I'm thinking about is to use the modulo operator, but I believe this wouldn't allow me to choose which column I want to pop as this is a stack.

Is my first idea reasonable or is there another approach to this?

Comment: Why do you want a vector of stack? I would be thinking of a stack of vector/array instead. Also what is that `int* _stack` for?

Comment: What is your metric for most efficient? Do you measure number of operations? What weight does each operation have? Do you measure speed? On what CPU? Dpending on how you define most efficient using a `std::forward_list` or `std::vector` could be most efficient. Since it's 2D you can mix and match giving you 4 choices to profile. And then you could do small vector optimization. Copying 6 ints is way faster than a `new` call. Your simple example would be faster representing the rows as an array of 6 ints if you copy them around a lot.